# Why I can't make Overrides on my Prefab after made some position changes for the Prefab?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: Prefab]

I dragged the FPEPlayerController Prefab to the Hierarchy and changed it's position on X,Y,Z
But n ow when I click on the Overrides it says No Overrides so I can't save the changes I did to the Prefab.

[image: Prefab no Overrides]

The only place in the Hierarchy I'm using now the prefab is in the FPECore :
But not sure if that make the problem that there are no Overrides.
There are no Overrides also on the FPECore.

[image: Prefab]

Comment: Position is irrelevant for prefabs, basically. When you call `Instantiate` you have the option to pass in a position (or let the default optional parameter value of `0,0,0` be applied)

Comment: I believe it’s because that’s the global position and that isn’t important for a prefab since it should be given a position upon instantiation. If you want to change the prefabs position you could also go into the prefab editor then manually change its position.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Unity doesn't care about the position of the object in prefabs.</strike> Best thing to do is when you Instantiate it, call it with any of these:

```
GameObject g = Instantiate(prefabName, position, rotation);
GameObject g = Instantiate(prefabName, position, rotation, parentName);
GameObject g = Instantiate(prefabName, parentName, instantiateInWorldSpace);
```

if you're using the last one, you can set the position and rotation after instantiating.

More info on Instantiate:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

EDIT: Thanks to Ron for reminding me about what prefabs do with their saved values

Comment: This is incorrect, if you call Instantiate without giving a specific position, it will instantiate said prefab in it's saved position. That being said, I find that it's better practice to never count on the prefab's transform values.

Comment: @Ron really? I thought it would get instantiated on `0,0,0` by default

Comment: @derHugo are you stalking me? :) yeah if you'll save a prefab at `10,0,0` for example and you call `Instantiate` with only the prefab, it will be spawned at world position  `10,0,0`

Comment: @Ron this question was asked yesterday, I'm not stalking anyone ^^ I just thought I had have different experiences in the past, but I tested it and you are right!

Comment: @derHugo I'm asking that because I woke up to 4 notifications - all comments from you :)